# Get console screen from AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to get physical console screen from Amazon server like I seat in front of physical server screen.

The server hang and I can not ssh to server after reboot so I need this console.

How can I do that.

Thanks.

Comment: The public IP of an instance will change after reboot unless you've associated an instance to an elastic IP. Are you sure you're trying to  SSH to the correct public IP?

Comment: I know this, my instance map with elastic IP. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the console log, but EC2 does not provide direct access to the console. If you find the problem and need to make changes. You can do so if you are using EBS volumes by attaching the volume to a new instance. If you are using instance storage, you will be out of luck.

Comment: Thank you. I want to add reputation but under limit.